# Vue/Typescript How to find right type of object used for style = { }

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I use this approach for style in my vue ts project.

```js
    private styleTableObject: CSSStyleSheet = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '76%'
    }
```

I am forced to the `any` type.

```js
    private styleTableObject: any = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '76%'
    }
```

Error logs:

```
Type '{ width: string; height: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSStyleSheet'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'width' does not exist in type 'CSSStyleSheet'.
```

If a use any type from visual code helper i got error logs:

```
 Type '{ width: string; height: string; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleSheet'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'width' does not exist in type 'StyleSheet'.

219:13 Type '{ width: string; height: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CSSStyleDeclaration': alignContent, alignItems, alignSelf, alignmentBaseline, and 382 more.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` instead

> **Partial<T>**
>
> Constructs a type with all properties of T set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type

From: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt

So your code will look like this

```js
private styleTableObject: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '76%'
}
```

Comment: This solution will throw errors in more recent projects. I haven't checked what exactly has changed and which update causes the errors but a better way to evade those errors is following the answer of kyis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71632919/1602864

Answer (score 6):

Vue 3 provides its own type for CSS property objects. Note `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` will cause type checking errors in your template (i.e. with Volar enabled):

```
import type { CSSProperties } from 'vue'

const styleTableObject: CSSProperties = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '76%'
}

<div :style="styleTableObject" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So that is helpful, this seems to work:

```
const style: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> = {};
const arrowStyle: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> = {};

const data = ref({
 strokeWidth: 0.108,
 style: style,
 arrowStyle: arrowStyle,
});
```

But is there a way to do it without the separate variables right when defining const data?

Comment: I didn't notice this earlier, but now I'm getting errors in the template itself, which doesn't seem to like the type<CSSStyleDeclarartion>